# Preposition + having been + Past participle

Tags: passive-voice, active-vs-passive

As far as I know, Having been is mostly used to tell background information. For instance :

> *Having been taught grammar, I started speaking english.*

However, I have seen many times it is used with prepositions 'for' and 'of'. Can someone please describe its function with different prepositions?

> *BSNL, for its part, was saddled with the legacy of having been a large-scale provider of jobs as well as state-mandated connectivity to remote corners of the country.*

> *In many states appointments are being challenged for having been made on political ground.*

In the second sentence, I think it's being  used to tell the reason and *for* is functioning like a *because*. I would have written that sentence in this way :

> *In many states appointments are being challenged because they have been made on political ground.*

1. Am i correct? If no, please explain its functioning?
2. In the first sentence I cannot understand the usage of *of having been*. Please explain what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second sentence you are right.

The first sentence needs to be split up a bit. It says that BSNL had been a large-scale provider of jobs as well as state-mandated connectivity to remote corners of the country. The main thrust of the sentence is that BSNL, for its part, was saddled with this legacy, that is the legacy of having been a large-scale provider etc. "Having" is the beginning of a long noun phrase.